# POWER BI Save Visualised table into a new table (internal data export)

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

couldn't find an answer for this anywhere.
let's say we have 3 tables, when i visualize the join between them i get a table displayed on the screen, i want to save this table as static as it is (for ex in databases we create views)

i want to use this table and to make more process on it (like i could export it inside the file as table and not only as excel or csv)

[image: example]

note that some of tables can be a calculation tabs. I don't deal with it on intern without export. I tried to create a new table that makes the join, but the data is somehow unrelated to perform it and sometimes there is 4 or 5 tables in the path to get the join, which PBI do it auto.

Comment: Use Power Query to join the tables and perform the other ETL and data cleansing steps. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-query-overview?msclkid=9cf3ee8acf9311ec8b57cd6f6c31bf30

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft this won't answer my question, some of columns are measure and the selection is from multiple table i generated locally on PBI and not external import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated table with the DAX formula you require.

```
myNewTable = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table[Colonne 1],'Table (2)'[Colonne 1],'Table (3)'[Colonne 1])
```

Comment: it doesn't work with a measure table, if for ex table2 columns are measures

Comment: Adjust... You can reference measures too... just put `"output name", [Measure],` instead after all the columns [SUMMARIZECOLUMNS](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/dax/summarizecolumns-function-dax)

Comment: can you suggest something to get a strict join and to not get NULL element. The table is well generated but contains 600 elements instead of 10, like it's a full join

Comment: better create a new question with more details, like sample data and expected output